# IAM Policy to restore RDS from S3 Bucket not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am trying to restore a snapshot in parquet format that is stored in S3. But I am getting the error

**"An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RestoreDBInstanceFromS3 operation: Files from the specified Amazon S3 bucket cannot be downloaded. Make sure that you have created an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that lets Amazon RDS access Amazon S3 for you."**.

Here is the IAM policy I created:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ImportPolict",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Trusted relationship configured on the role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the command I am using: `aws rds restore-db-instance-from-s3 --allocated-storage 150 --db-instance-identifier instanceName --db-instance-class db.t2.medium --engine mysql --master-username user --master-user-password password --s3-bucket-name bucket-name --s3-ingestion-role-arn arnToRole --source-engine mysql --source-engine-version 5.6.44`

This user has access to the S3 Bucket and there is nothing configured on Bucket Policy

Answer (score 7):

if you used KMS for encrypting bucket or object you need to give access to KMS. I created that policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and added it to role which I used while restoring the DB.
Note that: That policy can be much wider than required.

Comment: This worked for me, although I then got the error "Files from the specified Amazon S3 bucket are encrypted. Restoring from encrypted S3 object is not available" So I think you can encrypt the dump using KMS but cannot enable encryption on the bucket itself.

Comment: Worked! Make sure to hit the refresh button for the IAM role in your DB create page.